# Godfinger -- fishing is flaky?

Tags: godfinger

In [Godfinger](http://godfinger.ngmoco.com/), for some reason, my followers randomly refuse to fish in lakes or seas I made. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any idea why, and how can I get them fishing more reliably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure they have some energy first before placing them by a pond. They will not fish if completely exhausted. Also, make sure the pond edge is not a stiff cliff where they can't reach the water.

([Source: NGMoco support](http://getsatisfaction.com/ngmoco/topics/in_god_finger_how_do_the_people_get_energy))

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and aside from a few tips, there isn't much you can do, it's just flaky AI.

Try to make sure the water level in your pond is as close to the bank as possible (i.e. fill it up as much as you can.)  The best way I found to do this is to fill it past the full point, then use the *Sun* evaporate the overflow.

Try to get steeper sides on your pools.  I found that having a nice, sharp edge to drop my villagers on made quite a difference, at times.  Go for 90 degrees, if possible.

Also, try to place your villager as close to the edge of the pool as possible (without dunking them, of course).  A lot of times, my villagers seemed to not see the pool unless they had been dropped *quite* near to the edge.